# How to resolve ELK Stack Mapping Conflict for apache access combined logs

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, mapping, conflict, logstash-grok

I am trying to learn ELK stack where i have staretd with indexing apache   access logs, i have Logstash 1.4.2,Elasticseach 1.5.1 and kiabna 4.0.2 for windows. Following are my configurtion files. for **mapping at elasticsearch** i have used

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/apache_access?ignore_conflicts=true -d '{  
    "settings" : {  
          "number_of_shards" : 1  
    },  
    "mappings" : {  
        "apache" : {  



 "properties" : {

"timestamp" : {"type":"date", "format" : "DD/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss" },             
"bytes": {"type": "long"},   
"response":{ "type":"long"},  
"clientip":{ "type": "ip"},  
"geoip" : { "type" : "geo_point"}  
}  
        }  
    }  
}'
```

and my **logstash-apache.conf** is

```
input   {  
  file {
    path => "D:\data\access_log1.log"  
    start_position => beginning  
    }
}

filter {


    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    }
    geoip{
    source => "clientip"
    target => "geoip"
    }

  date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ,"ISO8601"]
  }
}

output {  
  elasticsearch {  
            host => "localhost"  
            protocol => http  
            index => "apache_access"    
    }  
      stdout { codec => rubydebug }  
}
```

what i am facing is , for the fields for which i have applied mapping in elasticsearch i.e bytes,response,clientip i am getting conflict. i understand what is happening, as it says these fields have string and long both as field type. but i dont understand why it is happening as i have  applied mapping. i would also like to resolve this issue. any help is appreciated.

Comment: it got solved a version upgrade.